# Vagrant ssh : garbage at end of line

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ssh-keys

Trying to install vagrant for laravel project
All was nice just till the moment I tryed to create vagrant ssh with command:
vagrant ssh
I have next error:

command-line line 0: garbage at end of line;"chil/project/Homestead/.vagrant/machines/homestead-7/virtualbox/private_key".

I think it's because of path, because I have folder illia_chil (firts folder in the path)

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 10):

It is because of the path, but an underscore shouldn't have caused this error. I had this error due to having spaces in my path.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in your path, use double quotes. That resolved the issue for me.